# Передача учетных данных из Windows в скрипт Python

Tags: python, авторизация, active-directory, scripts

Всем привет. В моем python скрипте идет подключение к AD с помощью либы ldap3, и данные для подключения (которые вообще-то секретные), я передаю совсем не безопасно - обычной строкой, и логин, и пароль, даже в незашифрованном виде. Учитывая то, что данные на вход в ОС для запуска скрипта и данные для подключения к AD идентичны полностью, то можно наверно их как-то вытянуть в скрипт из ОС...  И как мне эти данные передать в скрипт из ОС - я не понимаю даже, что мне загуглить . Я только начал изучать python, и новичок в этом, поэтому прошу помощи у аудитории, куда хоть копать?

```
AD_SERVER = 'domain.com.ru'
AD_USER = 'adminname@domain.com.ru'
AD_PASSWORD = 'adminpassword'
AD_SEARCH_TREE = 'dc=domain,dc=com,dc=ru'

server = Server(AD_SERVER)
conn = Connection(server, user=AD_USER, password=AD_PASSWORD)
conn.bind()
```

Вот часть скрипта, и я пытаюсь понять, можно ли как-то обойти передачу логина/пароль в виде строки как предопределенных данных и в тот же час без доп. запросов от скрипта, типа "Введите свой пароль". Ведь админ залогинен на сервере уже с нужными скрипту данными авторизации.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я удалил свой ответ, так как похоже, автор вопроса действительно не понимает, что он делает.

Comment: Почему не понимаю? Я хочу разобраться, возможно ли вообще как-то это сделать? Зря Вы удалили ответ, я хотел попробовать указанные Вами методы и посмотреть на результат. Я только учусь.

Comment: в Ваших комментариях было слишком много стоп-слов для меня.

Comment: Ну, в таком случае, теперь Вы меня извините...